# Overwrite CSS rule background color with opacity

Tags: css

I have the following rules

```
.homeSearch li {
    background-color: rgba(144,178,59, 0.8);
    background: rgba(144,178,59, 0.8);
    color: rgba(144,178,59, 0.8);
}
```

But when i try to override the background color on the hover of the `li`, because the background color that i give is again in rgba, the override keeps also the previous colors.

```
.homeSearch li a:hover, .homeSearch li a.active{
    background-color: rgba(40,65,113, 0.8) !important;
    background: rgba(40,65,113, 0.8) !important;
}
```

Comment: Try changing li a:hover to li:hover

Comment: When you hover on `a` it applies background color to `a` while original background color is applied on `li` is also there.. better move background color to `a` as well..

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, that was the problem! If you want post your answer to mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1):

CSS should be (`no need !important`):

```
.homeSearch li:hover, 
.homeSearch li.active{
    background-color: rgba(40,65,113, 0.8);
    background: rgba(40,65,113, 0.8);
}
```